# Tabla, Header tamaño fijo y Fixed en Bootstrap 3 y Css3.

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, css3

**Problema :** 
Definirle un ancho a la primera columna, que esta quede fija, y que el scroll este sobre las demás columnas.

**Esperado :**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Requisitos :** El único requisito es que debe estar realizado en BOOTSTRAP 3 con CSS3.

**Actual :**

```css
table {
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fijar
{
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-responsive display compact no-wrap">
    <thead>
        <tr id="chargedaysheader">
            <th width="60%" class="headcol" rowspan="2" style="width: 30%;color: white; clear: both; table-layout: fixed; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #0094ff;">FIXED</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="chargelegendheader">
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="chargetabledata">
        <tr>
           <td class="fijar">FIXED</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fijar">FIXED</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>1.9T</td>
            <td>38.1%</td>
            <td>15.0T</td>
            <td>83.6%</td>
            <td>8.6T</td>
            <td>22.6%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fijar">FIXED</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class="fijar">FIXED</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>7.5T</td>
            <td>43.6%</td>
            <td>19.4T</td>
            <td>41.0%</td>
            <td>27.7T</td>
            <td>74.0%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class="fijar">FIXED</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>12.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>7.6T</td>
            <td>38.9%</td>
            <td>532.8T</td>
            <td>5.7%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: **¿El html no puede cambiar?** Digo porque así tal cual como esta, más que dificil lograrlo es algo "imposible" de lograr.  **Aunque creo que es posible hacerlo, pero modificando el Html** ya que se podría emular algo muy similar via css, pero no aseguro solo con bootstrap, sino más bien usando un arsenal CSS3 a la medida (aunque compatible con la versión que usas del framework). ¿Que me dices?

Comment: la idea sería que no cambie el HTML, pero si me comentas que es imposible lograrlo de otro modo, me gustaría ver la propuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Revisa el siguiente ejemplo de nuestros amigos de 
[stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-scrollable-body)

```css
        body { font:16px Calibri;}
        table { border-collapse:separate; border-top: 3px solid grey; }
        td, th {
            margin:0;
            border:3px solid grey; 
            border-top-width:0px; 
            white-space:nowrap;
        }
        div { 
            width: 600px; 
            overflow-x:scroll;  
            margin-left:5em; 
            overflow-y:visible;
            padding-bottom:1px;
        }
        .headcol {
            position:absolute; 
            width:5em; 
            left:0;
            top:auto;
            border-right: 0px none black; 
            border-top-width:3px; /*solo primera fila*/
            margin-top:-4px; /*compensa el borde superior*/
        }
        .headcol:before {content: 'fila ';}
        .long { background:#ccc; letter-spacing:1em; }
```

```html
<div><table>
        <tr><th class="headcol">1</th><td class="long">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">2</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">3</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">4</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">5</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">6</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td></tr>
        
</table></div>
```

Comment: No funciona en mi ejemplo. Como dije arriba estoy utilizando Bootstrap 3, y en el primer TH estoy usando rowspan="2".

Answer (score 1):

Basado en esta [respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36267922/4914734)

Según lo que nos dice la W3C en cuanto a [posicionar y flotar celdas de una tabla](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-CSS21-20060411/tables.html#q7)

> Posicionar y flotar celdas en una tabla puede hacer que ya no sean celdas, de acuerdo a las reglas en la sección [9.7](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-CSS21-20060411/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo). Cuando se usa a flotación, las reglas en los objetos anónimos de las tablas pueden causar que una celda anónima también sea creada.

Osea que si utilizamos `position: absolute` que es la única manera que se me ocurre hacerlo, da igual usar `rowspan` ya que las celda no será representada como parte de la tabla.

Dicho eso una solución puede ser declarar el doble de alto al `th` que usarás como header, y declarar un `th` "invisible" para que nos ayude con la segunda fila.

Siento que hay una gran desventaja con esta solución y es que necesitamos saber el alto de las dos primeras filas y el ancho de la columna que quedará fija, pero es la única manera que encontré de hacerlo.

```css
table {
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th {
  height: 4rem; /* Alto fijo de las dos primeras filas */
}

.fijar-headcol {
  position: absolute;
  height: 8rem; /*Doble de alto de la primera fila*/
  background-color: #0F0;
  /* Centramos */
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.headcol {
  display: block;
  width: 8rem; /* Ancho fijo de la primera columna */
}

.fijar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 8rem; /* Ancho fijo de la primera columna */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-responsive display compact no-wrap">
        <thead>
          <tr id="chargedaysheader">
            <th class="headcol fijar-headcol">FIXED</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
            <th colspan="2">X</th>
          </tr>
          <tr id="chargelegendheader">
            <th scope="row" class="headcol">
              <div class="sr-only">FIXED</div>
            </th><!-- Utilizo esto para lograr un espacio entre las th fijas y las td, de paso nos ayudará con la accesibilidad -->
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
            <th>XXXXXXXXXXXX</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="chargetabledata">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="fijar">FIXED</th>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="fijar">FIXED</th>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>100.0%</td>
            <td>1.9T</td>
            <td>38.1%</td>
            <td>15.0T</td>
            <td>83.6%</td>
            <td>8.6T</td>
            <td>22.6%</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="fijar">FIXED</th>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
            <td>0.0T</td>
            <td>0.0%</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```